# Expected ',' or '...' before numeric const

Tags: c++, c

I am new in C programming and trying to figure out some problems encountered. 
When I wrote

```
#define N 5

void Sort(int *const array,  int N);
```

the compiler gave me the message "Expected ',' or '...' before numeric const". After searching on the internet and found out that the problem may be casued by the #define being debugged as numeric values. I did get through the compiler by not using the #define for the constant N. However, I wondered how should I modified the above two lines so that I won't get that error message?

Comment: Consider your code is equivalent to `void Sort(int *const array, int 5);`. This is nonsensical.

Comment: @In silico, any particular reason why you retagged to C only? This a valid question and a pitfall for both languages.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: Because the OP said "I am new in C programming".

Answer (score 12):

You're using the preprocessor which runs on the raw text of the program before the compiler even sees it. So in this case **all** occurrences of `N` (when the `N` is by itself, not part of another word) get replaced by `5`. By the time the program gets to the compiler, due to the preprocessor, all it sees is:

```
void Sort(int *const array,  int 5);
```

Which is invalid syntax, and that's why you're getting the error.

---

### C or C++

Either use a different name for the `#define`, or change your parameter name to any other valid identifier. The latter would look like this:

```
#define N 5

void Sort(int *const array,  int number);
```

One other option would be to not use variable names in the function prototype:

```
#define N 5

void Sort(int *const, int);
```

But then you still have the problem of naming it in the actual function definition.

Note that even just changing the case of the letter (from `N` to `n`) would fix it, but don't do that because it might look ambiguous to someone.

---

### C++

If you are using C++, you shouldn't use `#define` (avoid it as much as you can, because they are [bad](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/inline-functions.html#faq-9.5) [in](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.4) [myriad](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.5) [ways](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.6)). You should prefer a `const int`:

```
const int N = 5;
```

You can use this just about anywhere you could use the other, plus it won't break when people try to use that name for themselves, and it won't cause multiple definitions like it would in C (thanks Jens). For example, your original code would have worked if you'd used a constant instead of `#define`:

```
const int N = 5;

void Sort(int *const array,  int N); // works because N is a real variable
```

Comment: Your idea to use a `const`-qualified variable is not a good idea for C, but only for C++. This is one of the points where the two languages differ substantially, for C this easily gives you multiply defined symbols. For C one could use `enum { N = 5 };` here to have a similar effect.

Comment: Even if this is a bad practice his question is still valid. It is very possible to have macro name collision when you use third party libraries on which you don't have any control.

Comment: @Jens oh wow, how did I get into the C section? Sorry, thought this was C++, fixing.

Comment: @Sasha I didn't mean to indicate his question was invalid.

Comment: Thank you all for the explanation.

Comment: Originally this was tagged with both C and C++. I don't know why the C++ tag was deleted. It is definitively a question that is relevant for both.

Comment: @Stacy make sure you mark the answer that answered your question as the answer by clicking the check mark near the top left of the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You `#define` a macro that is expanded by the preprocessor before the compiler sees the code.  So, the compiler gets:

```
void Sort(int *const array, int 5);
```

This is not valid C syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged as C++, I suggest to stop using `#define` for the purpose of defining constants:

```
const int N = 5;
int f(int N); // works
```

If you're forced to use preprocessor, give your macros long ugly names to avoid name-clashes:

```
#define YOUR_MEANINGFUL_CONSTANT_NAME_GOES_HERE 5
int f(int N); // works;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using N for a macro, `#define N 5` and N for a variable name, `int N`. This is a bad idea. The usual convention is to reserve all capital names for macros. So in this case I would recommend changing `int N` to `int n`. Avoid careless use of macros, they cause exactly this sort of problem. But if you do use macros give them more meanful names than 'N' to minimise the chance of this kind of mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For VS compiler you can do this:

```
#define N 5

#ifdef N
    #pragma push_macro("N") 
    #undef N

    #define REDEFINE_N
#endif

void Sort(int *const array,  int N);

#ifdef REDEFINE_N
    #pragma pop_macro("N")
#endif
```

Comment: He he it is ugly but sometimes you just have no choice :-)